# Haskell: same module found twice - "Ambiguous module name"

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have the following import in a haskell file. I'm using cabal.

```
import Network.Wai (Application, Response, rawPathInfo, responseFile, responseLBS, requestBody)
```

But I'm getting this error when I try to build the file:

```
Error: Ambiguous module name ‘Network.Wai’:
  it was found in multiple packages: wai-3.2.2.1 wai-3.2.2.1
```

Note that the multiple packages are *exactly the same*. Something like -XPackageImports doesn't work here, because for some reason the same package is installed twice.

I opened up `/Users/<user>/.cabal/store/ghc-8.6.5/package.db` and sure enough, there were two "w" (wai) packages with the same version but different hashes. I deleted one and this didn't fix it.

Comment: Tried deleting the other and it still didn't fix it.

Comment: How do you try and build?

Comment: This is using Sublime Text 3's SublimeHaskell plugin, and the builtin linter/builder there. Let me see if I can get it to throw this error from a cli command.

Comment: I do believe your cmd attempt will fail. I only know to say "use stack". If that's not an option you'll have to get some help with sublime.

Comment: Hm, if I load it using `:l MyFileName` it loads properly. I can also actually build the file and it runs. Maybe this is a bug with the SublimeHaskell linter / checker.

Comment: Gonna try rebuilding this whole thing with stack

Comment: What is your cabal version, and what command are you running to try to build?

Comment: cabal-install version 3.0.0.0, the command is the default sublimehaskell build command (??)

Comment: I rebuilt it using stack last night but now my build/run loop is *much* longer so I'd like to go back to cabal if possible.